# Serializing Anchors in AR Core

Tags: arcore

Is it possible to somehow serialize/save Anchors, so that I can have a persistent offline trackability?

For example, I have a 3D scene to detect, which should be shareable and trackable for a long time. In order to do this, I think I need either a private cloud server for Anchors or offline anchor files so that they can be shared on multiple devices over a period of time.

Is it somehow possible with AR Core?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

ARCore supports cloud anchors which meet what I think you are asking for, except for the 'long time' part.

At the moment they only fully support 1 day persistence - longer is apparently on the roadmap but at the time of writing there is no date (AFAIK).

There are 3rd party solutions which do offer this - take a look at 6D.ai for example: https://www.6d.ai/faq/ - this claims to support Persistence:

> Persistence - objects stay in the world where you left them